# Java + Steam авторизация

Tags: java, steam

есть ли возможность реализовать авторизацию в моем приложении через steam? Знаю о Steam Web Api но это только для веб сайтов, на сколько я понимаю.

Comment: Возможность есть!

Comment: @ Дмитрий Матвиенко поделитесь информацией? где можно почитать?)

Comment: Это сервлет или что? Для работы с OpenID нужны колбеки в вашем приложении.